# Excel calling a function of a C++ program

Tags: c++, excel

1. I have a C++ program, program.exe that has a function doSomething()
2. But instead of having a logic in program.exe to call doSomething(), I need excel to be the frontend to decide when to call this doSomething()  - based on some changes in a particular cell
3. XML/CSV IO is out because the decision making is in realtime, low latency
4. So how do I go about interfacing excel with program.exe in order for excel to invoke doSomething()

I do hope someone could point me in a direction. Im using QT 4.8.5 to develop the c++ project.
I've been reading , but COM models are very new to me.. Do i write a COM model? DLL?

how would the COM/DLL "know" that excel has invoked it and thus provide some sort of "acknowledgement" and in turn invoke the doSomething() in program.exe?

Comment: You are using excel for a real-time application?

Comment: yup.. it'l be realtime

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to create a DLL containing your function `doSomething` and call it from Excel as described in this MSDN article: [How to: Access DLLs in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915.aspx)

You could also make a COM component out of your application. This would be a bit easier to access from Excel (especially when it comes to argument types), but if you've never done it (and you only need to call one single function) it might be better to try the "pure-DLL"-approach first.

Answer (score 0):

You can call DLL functions from excel.
With that, you've got 2 possibilities:

- Convert your program into a DLL.
- If that's not possible, create a DLL which communicates with your program (over some IPC mechanism, like sockets for example)

For details, search the Web or ask again :-)

> how would the COM/DLL "know" that excel has invoked it and thus
>   provide some sort of "acknowledgement" and in turn invoke the
>   doSomething() in program.exe

Excel doesn't invoke the DLL, it invokes a function in the DLL (by calling it from a VBA macro or a spreadsheet formula). When this function is executing, it must have been called by something (probably Excel, unless you call it from somewhere else) so it kind of "knows" that it's been called. And it can provide feedback to excel through it's return value.

Answer (score 0):

PE files (.exe) does not export functions. You can however execute your program from excel with arguments and use the results (read stdout from the program into excel).

You can use a macro to execute the program. However, I refuse to write Visual Basic (or read it for that matter), so unfortunately I'm unable to supply any example code. It should be easily available if you search around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

anyw.. i eventually found an example that i can understand  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/activeqt-comapp.html

the final VBA code is something that can be easily incorporated in Excel-vba and QT provides a ?easy? way to write a COM wrapper over my existing codes